# Python_ prompt from user multiple variables in single line and call each variables in a new line

Tags: python

everyone.
I'm quite nervous to ask this question and I'm not sure that this title is well explained my questions content..
by anyway, here is my question.

e.g.
I want to receive 5 varibles but in seperated line but i want to declare all the variables in single line

```
a,b,c,d,e = int(input(); // I know this won't work.. but this is the way kind of what i want.
```

and here is my input given

```
10 // this is assigned to a
40 // assigned to b
30 // assigned to c
50 // assigned to d
20 // assigned to e
```

normally i give inputs in single line seperated by ' ' as below.

```
10 40 30 50 20
```

and i usually received this inputs as below.

```
a,b,c,d,e = map(int,input().split());
```

but this time i want to try something different way as i asked.

////////////////////
i found some article which are related to this question [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-input-multiple-values-from-user-in-one-line-in-python).
there is written as below.

```
>>> x, y, z = input(), input(), input()
40
30
10
>>> x
'40'
>>> y
'30'
>>> z
'10'
```

but this is not satisfying since it uses input() too much.
I think maybe there is someway to reduce input() as one or whatever..

is there any solution guide for this?
thank you for reading till now!
have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should this instead

```
  >>>a,b,c,d,e,f = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

> **This will output**

```
>>> a,b,c,d,e,f = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
15 24 12 47 52 25
>>> a
15
>>> b
24
>>> c
12
>>> d
47
>>> e
52
>>> f
25
```

Comment: thank you! i think this is what i was looking for!
compared to other solution this seems using input() only one time! haha thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `map()` function, which executes a function passed as an argument on an iterable.

Here, for example, you can do the following:

```
>>> a, b, c = tuple(map(input, range(3)))
01
12
23
>>> a
'1'
>>> b
'2'
>>> c
'3'
```

`range(3)` creates a generator of 3 integers, which is passed to `map()` along with the input function. The lack of `()` indicates we don't want to execute the function now, we merely want to inform `map()` that this is what it should execute for each iteration. The lot is enclosed within `tuple()` to trigger the execution of the map object returned by the map function.

Note that the '0', '1', '2' before the input shown above is auto-generated by Python, they were not manually input.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using list comprehensions as well:

```
a,c,b,d,e = [input() for i in range(0,5)]
```

a,b,c,d,e variables will contains the inputs from the user

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line of snippet:

```
a, b, c, d, e = [input() for i in range(5)]
```

The right side creates an array of 5 elements, and every element calls the function `input()` of which the value is attributed.